# Leo Bootstrap Megamenu Error In Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, megamenu

I'm starting to learn Prestashop, so I've downloaded a free theme and started to edit it. But I have a problem with the navbar and now I need to edit it.

This is my navbar:

[image]

I need to add all my categories to the category section of the navbar, but I'm not able to do it. This theme uses **Leo Bootstrap Mega Menu**. So when I edited that module to add a product, it gives me the following error:

[image]

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your theme or module uses a function that is not included in your version of Prestashop. Try to put this function in your classes/Language.php file before the last `}`.

```
/**
 * Returns an array of language IDs.
 *
 * @param bool     $active  Select only active languages
 * @param int|bool $id_shop Shop ID
 *
 * @return array
 */
public static function getIDs($active = true, $id_shop = false)
{
    return self::getLanguages($active, $id_shop, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for @Roman K suggestion. I recommend you should add the code to overrides folder. It will be easier for you when you upgrade to new version of Prestashop.

If you still get the error. I think you should download other [Prestashop Mega Menu Module](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/menu/29701-mega-menu-builder.html).